# Handling "Send to" in MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to add support for "Send to" from window explorer right click context menu feature into my MFC application. For this I've parsed command line argument `m_lpCmdLine` in `InitInstance()` to get the file path and opened it. This is the case when application is not running.

But in case when application is already running. Then in this case I don't want to create a new instance.

What will be needed for passing these command line options, to already existing instance.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3126/Single-Instance-Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks I got the solution!

I need to find the handle of the open instance and the send message along with data which will be handle in CMainFrame class.

```
CWnd*  pCWnd;
if(pCWnd = CWnd::FindWindow(_T("MyApplication"), NULL))
{
    if(m_lpCmdLine != '\0')
    {
        COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
        memset(&cds, 0, sizeof(cds));

        cds.dwData = MY_ACTION;
        cds.cbData = strlen(m_lpCmdLine) + 1;
        cds.lpData = (LPVOID) (LPCTSTR)m_lpCmdLine;

        pCWnd->SendMessage(WM_COPYDATA,(WPARAM)NULL, (LPARAM)&cds);
    }
}
```

Now in,

```
MainFrame::OnCopyData()
{
}
```

we can get this value.

For more detail description, read inter-process communication chapter of "Multithreading Application in Win32".